# How to add dropdown to react-table on click of icon

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using react table 7.0 , How can i add and iconColumn , and on click of that , need to show an dropdown.

```
 {
        Header: "",
        accessor: "actionColumn",
        disableSortBy: true,
        Cell: ({ original }) => (
           
            <div className="cursor__pointer ">
                <Icon className="padding5" iconName="RemoveLink" aria-hidden="true" />
            </div>
        )
    },
```

I am able to render an icon on the column like above. How can i render a dropdown on click of it ?

Comment: Are you using some components library? If no - then you can check them - a lot of them have dropdown components, like here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/
If you don't want to include whole library for that, then you can also add single component like this one: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown

Comment: But , how do i tell react-table to render a dropdown on click of that icon ? not able to figure that out..

Comment: I've attached example below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example, how to do this with this simple [@trendmicro-frontend/react-dropdown](https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-dropdown) library:

```
      {
        Header: "",
        accessor: "actionColumn",
        disableSortBy: true,
        Cell: ({ original }) => (

            <div className="cursor__pointer ">
              <Dropdown
                  onSelect={(eventKey) => {
                  }}
              >
                <Dropdown.Toggle btnStyle="link" noCaret
                >
                  <Icon className="padding5" iconName="RemoveLink" aria-hidden="true" />
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Dropdown.Menu>
                  <MenuItem header>Header</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem eventKey={1}>link</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem divider />
                  <MenuItem header>Header</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem eventKey={2}>link</MenuItem>
                </Dropdown.Menu>
              </Dropdown>
            </div>
        )
      },
```

A working example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-leftpad-c6onr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks , the example does not have the dropdown .. But i get the idea

Comment: Sorry - my bad - changes were not saved, example should work now